# A 1 dimensional foliation which is Riemannian foliation with respect to no Riemannian metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

What is  an example of  a non vanishing smooth vector field on a manifold $M$ whose corresponding foliation is a Riemannian foliation with respect to no Riemannian metric on $M$

Comment: A closed leaf in a Riemannian foliation cannot have an asymptote.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin   Dear  Anton  Thank you for  your kind attention to my question and your very helpful  answer. BTW in the reference list of the  book of  Toendeur I had found a title of a paper some things like "on stability of  Riemannian foliation" But I did not read the paper. Then I post this question here. Is your idea parallel to this paper  mentioned in the  (very long) bibliography of Tondeur book? How does orthogonality of leaf-geodesics relate to non existence of limit cycle?